# Can I pair my Android device to my Kubuntu VM using KDE Connect?

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, kde-connect

I am using VirtualBox on an Samsung Windows 8.1 as host and Kubuntu 19.10 as the VM. Can I use **KDE Connect** to pair my Android device to the VM? And if yes, what ports do I need to open up for forwarding?

**EDIT 6:37PM 1-31-2020 (PH Standard Time)**: I am using **NAT** as my network adapter. Should I use *Bridged* option or add those ports manually on **Windows Firewall Advanced Options**?

Comment: `sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp` & `sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp` & `sudo ufw reload` from the section titled *Troubleshooting* in https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect. But I think you may need wi-fi; I'm not sure.

Comment: I also get the impression that the devices need to be on the same network.